# How to deal with ants in wall

Tags: pest-control

I have a pretty bad ant infestation.  I think the little critters are Argentine ants.  I've used a couple of bottles of Terro (I usually put down about a quarter bottle at a time).  It does slow them down, but they come right back not after not too long.

I have been thinking about using an aerosol insecticide.  The stuff I have has imiprothrin and cypermethrin as active ingredients.  The are supposed to be good enough that I can just spray on their trails, and they'll die if they walk over the sprayed areas.

The problem is the location of the trail.  They're coming out from a space between the baseboard heater and the wall's outer finish.

Can I spray the baseboard heater?  I'm not worried about fires, but I'd really hate for the insecticide to start outgassing when the heaters get turned on this winter.

Comment: Don't use spay.  It never works.

Answer (score 4):

You should lay a bait down.  I recommend Advion, which is a product from DuPont or MaxForce, which uses fipronil.  You can do a search on Amazon or a similar site for "Advion ant" or "MaxForce ant". The bait comes in a plunger that you can use to apply in small places.  Find out where they are trailing and put a few drops down.  You can put the drops on paper if you are worried about your finish.  Every day (or couple of hours if you have a bad infestation) check to see if the bait's gone and reapply.  It may take a couple of weeks to kill them all.

As far as Terro goes, I haven't had much luck with it either.  The attractant in Terro's all sugar-based from my understanding.  The ants may be feeding on Protein now.

Comment: Good idea.  I used the roach Advion when I moved into a different apartment last year.  The ants definitely eat the Terro by the hundreds.  Argentine ants can have hundreds of queens in a colony! :(

Comment: The fipronil was good, but the stuff I got is sensitive to drying out apparently, and then they can't eat anymore. Pretty wasteful, unless you just use very tiny beads, I mean small. I'm in a temperate climate... It definitely helps fight our super colony, but hasn't eliminated it by a long shot. Their interest also seems to wax and wane, very strange. I ended making my own little foil "cups" for this stuff, because it is nasty, and a PITA to clean up dried little globs of it...

Answer (score 0):

Anything citrus they hate! Cinnamon. Apple cider vin. Comet. Most of all that lemon orange citrus they hate it. I put peels everywhere and cleaned with lemons. If you kill one, it sends out a scent to signal the others to stay away! Lemon oil, pick that up. I’ve even used vicks! For flies and gnats Irish spring soap. Whatever you do - don’t get the gel bc they don’t ever stop coming and you’ll get so skeeved.